# Installing Selenium2 for multiple languages

Tags: selenium

I have a centos server and would like to install selenium, primarily for taking browser screenshots. I'd like to be able to use selenium webdriver with Ruby, Python and PHP.

I'm having trouble grasping what needs to be installed for this. If I take Ruby as an example do I just install selenium webdriver for ruby - gem install selenium-webdriver - and this will take care of all dependencies such as selenium server, or do I have to install selenium server first.

And would there be any differences if trying to install multiple client drivers for the relevant languages.

Perhaps I'm over complicating matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install the selenium server (hub) which is based on Java.

As for the different languages, those are the clients, so it doesn't really matter as they all use the same protocol over HTTP to communicate with the server.

So once the server is running, you can indeed gem install selenium-webdriver and run tests via the server from a ruby test script.